# Trying to assign multiple onfocus events

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get multiple onfocus events to happen, but I just cannot seem to get it to work.  Only the first is picked up.

```
<script>
function myFunction1(x) {
    x.style.background = "lightblue" 
} 

function myFunction2(x) {
    x.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>

Enter your name: <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction1(this);myFunction2(this)">
```

The script is in between the head tags and does need to stay there.  I'm sure I am just missing something simple, but it seems the simple things are always the hardest to figure out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the function are being executed. You actually need to assign the value back to input with

```
 x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
```

```js
function myFunction1(x) {
    x.style.background = "lightblue" 
} 

function myFunction2(x) {
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
Enter your name: <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction2(this);myFunction1(this)">
```

But normally, I'd do by adding event handlers for that. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the very limiting inline event handlers, use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) this way you can add multiple listeners on the same element for the same type of event and have a seperation of concerns(html and js)

example usage

```
let myElem = document.querySelector(".my-elem");
myElem.addEventListener("focus", (ev) => { // one handler });
myElem.addEventListener("focus", (ev) => { // another handler });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working, the second function just doesn't return/log anything.

Use the [`onkeyup`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event:

```js
function myFunction1(x) {
  x.style.background = "lightblue"
}

function myFunction2(x) {
  x.value = x.value.toUpperCase()
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction1(this)" onkeyup="myFunction2(this)">
```

Comment: That didn't work either, I tried in both Firefox and Edge.  The text doesn't go to all caps at all.  Once the mouse leaves the text box, the entered text should turn to all caps, right?

Comment: @BradAnderson use the [`onkeyup`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this line:

```
x.value.toUpperCase();
```

Change that line to:

```
x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
```

You need to assign the result of **toUpperCase()** to the element.

```js
function myFunction1(x) {
    x.style.background = "lightblue"
}

function myFunction2(x) {
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
Enter your name: <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction1(this);myFunction2(this)">
```

You may also consider to use the three events:

- onfocus
- onblur
- onkeyup

```js
function myFunction1(x) {
  x.style.background = "lightblue"
}

function myFunction2(x) {
  x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}

function myFunction3(x) {
  x.style.background = "inherit"
}
```

```html
Enter your name: <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction1(this)" onblur="myFunction3(this)" onkeyup="myFunction2(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always combine them into one event listener. That way you don't clutter up your html with inline js and you can easily extend your focus handling by just adding another function to the `addEventListener`'s callback block.

```js
function myFunction1(x) {
  console.log('fn1 running');
  x.style.background = "lightblue"
}

function myFunction2(x) {
  console.log('fn2 running');
  x.value.toUpperCase();
}

const inp = document.querySelector('input');
inp.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  myFunction1(this);
  myFunction2(this);
});
```

```html
Enter your name: <input type="text">
```

And if you actually want to change the `input` value to upper case letters then you need to change this line

```
x.value.toUpperCase();
```

like this

```
x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
```

And if you want to automatically convert letters to upper case as they are  being typed then you can use `input` event type for the second function instead of `focus` like this.

```js
function myFunction1(x) {
  console.log('fn1 running');
  x.style.background = "lightblue"
}

function myFunction2(x) {
  x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}

const inp = document.querySelector('input');
inp.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  myFunction1(this);
});
inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
  myFunction2(this);
});
```

```html
Enter your name: <input type="text">
```